# How to convert apache .htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How to convert below condition for nginx,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

I need to convert the apache .htaccess to Nginx configuration, if anyone knows the solution please help me, thanks.

Already I have converted .htaccess file to Nginx configuration by using some online tools,  but it's not working.

If I put the URL in the browser automatically downloaded the index.php file. I have checked info.php but fpm also working fine. I don't know how to fix this issue.

here i have mention my Nginx conf file:

```
server {

   server_name example.com;
   root /home/example/public_html;
   index  index.php;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/example/example-access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/example/example-error.log;

   location / {
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
}

   location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess) {
     deny all;
   }

 location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm-example.com.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 2022-03-18

As pointed out by @Danila Vershinin the `rewrite` statements should end with `last` instead of `break`.

---

You can try something like this

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 break;
}
```

or use a [converter](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) or [another converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx).

Comment: Already I tried this method, but it's not working. If I put the URL in the browser automatically downloaded the index.php file. I have checked info.php but fpm also working fine. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetPageSpeed converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) provides the correct result:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

Note the `last` directive. This is correct. It will make sure NGINX will start location search again to see which directives are applicable to rewritten URI `/index.php`. Then it finally ends up in your `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { ... }` and directives for processing with PHP-FPM will apply.

With `break`, things will not work, because there's no new location search after rewriting URL. The URI stays `/index.php` but directives from `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { ... }` will not be applied because NGINX didn't "go to" apply directives from it.

Comment: I tried this method also. If i used this configuration, the URL was continuously looped. 

if i give  http://example.com/admin/test ----> http://example.com/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/admin/test

getting this kind of error.

Comment: @kabilan.a make sure that the `rewrite` directives are placed *outside* any `location` block, as in the given example; also remove `try_files $uri =404;` from your configuration.